# Unable to see a network at all on client

Tags: networking

I am not able to see a network in my environment I have for a school project. I dont know exactly what I did so that it wont show up. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Suggestion? Have a question with some details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask